# Как обратиться к коллекции LinkedList

Tags: java, коллекции

Достаем из середины (не первый и не последний элемент) из коллекции и кладем в конец.
Пробовал пройтись циклом if но не получилось написать метод
код такой:

```
void django(String name){
    for(Integer i = 0;i<ListClass.size();i++){
        if (ListClass.get(i)!=ListClass.getFirst()&ListClass.get(i)!=ListClass.getLast()) {
            ListClass.get(i) = ListClass.getLast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что не получается то?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна помощь не могу решить такую задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136198/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83)

Comment: Дмитрий, пожалуйста, хватит плодить одинаковые тикеты

Answer (score 0):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы взять каждый элемент из середины списка и поместить его в конец, то вот вариант решения (для размера списка > 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("Первый", "Второй", "Третий", "Четвёртый", "Пятый"));
    System.out.println(list);
    shuffleList(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
static void shuffleList(List<String> list){
    if (list.size() > 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
            String element = list.get(1);
            list.remove(1);
            list.add(list.size(), element);
        }
    }
}
```

Работает как с LinkedList, так и с ArrayList. Вместо String можете подставить любой тип. 
В результате получим вывод в консоль:

```
[Первый, Второй, Третий, Четвёртый, Пятый]
[Первый, Пятый, Второй, Третий, Четвёртый]
```

По вашему коду:

1. Имена переменных пишем с маленькой буквы (listClass)
2. Если хотите проверять в цикле на первый и последний элемент, то проверять нужно не значение, а индекс. Но проще сделать цикл со второго элемента до предпоследнего.
3. Для чего вы передаёте String name в метод?
4. Как говорили другие комментаторы, учитесь лучше формулировать вопросы.

Comment: спасибо огромное,буду исправляться;)

Comment: можете объяснить,String element это обращение к элементу листа?расскажите подробнее если можно про присваивание String element = list.get(1);

Comment: String element = list.get(1) - это второй элемент списка (нумерация с нуля). Мы кладём значение в переменную element, чтобы затем добавить её в конец списка: list.add(list.size(), element). Удаляя в цикле второй элемент list.remove(1), весь список сдвигается влево. Т.о. в цикле достаточно каждый раз обращаться ко второму элементу.

Comment: Для лучшего понимания запустите приложение в режиме отладки (паучок), поставьте точку останова внутри цикла и по шагам смотрите, какие значения принимают переменные.

Comment: спасибо,буду пробовать)